# Password authentication problem in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, password, authentication

I had installed fingreprintd to make fingerprints work on my machine but it didn't recognize my fingerprint reader. So I removed the package. I think that it changed some desktop configurations so I verify with my fingerprint but now as I removed the package it didn't change them back and the desktop doesn't recognize my password. I can still log in but I can't use sudo or open app like timeshift and I can't unlock my screen after I locked it with Super + L. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I editet the file /etc/pam.d/common-auth and removed the lines:

```
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

I added those for the package to work and now everything works again!